# Contraction of metric with derivatives of 1-form components

Tags: riemannian-geometry, differential-forms, pullback

Let $(M,G)$ be a Riemannian metric and $V$ a $1$-form on $M$. Is there a coordinates-free, geometrical interpretation of the scalar $$G^{ij} \partial_i V_j$$
with summation over repeated indices understood?

In particular, let $\iota: S \hookrightarrow M $ be a submanifold of $M$, $g$ be the metric on $S$ induced by the ambient space metric, and $v$ be the pull-back of $V$ along the inclusion (hence a $1$-form on $S$).

Is the following true (for any choice of charts)?
$$\sum_{i,j = 1}^{\dim{S}} g^{ij}\partial_i v_j = \sum_{h,k = 1}^{\dim{M}} G^{hk}\partial_h V_k $$

**Context** This quantity appears computing the co-differential $\delta: \Omega^k \to \Omega^{k-1}$ of a $1$-form $V = V_i \,  dx^i$ :$$\delta V = V_i \,  \delta dx^i - G^{ij} \partial_i V_j$$
with $\Omega^k$ denoting the space of $k$-forms on a manifold; see e.g. Jürgen Jost, Riemannian Geometry and Geometric Analysis.

Comment: The quantity $G^{ij}\partial_iV_j$ certainly depends on the coordinates system. But so does the quantity $V_i\delta dx^i = -V_i g^{jk}(\nabla_{\partial_j}dx^i)(\partial_k)$. Its the whole combination $V_i\delta dx^i - G^{ij}\partial_iV_j$ that has a geometric meaning: it is $-\mathrm{trace}(\nabla V)$.